# Function return type depending on whether optional argument is passed

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function with return type depending on whether optional parameter (factory) was passed or not

- if it was passed then return type should be equal to factory return type
- else it should be any

I tried to do it like this:

```js
type Factory<T> = (data: any) => T;

function getObject<T>(id: number, factory?: Factory<T>): Factory<T> extends undefined ? any : ReturnType<Factory<T>> {
  let obj; // some entity from db in real app
  return factory ? factory(obj) : obj;
}

getObject(1, () => new Date()).getDate();             // OK, treated as date
getObject(1, () => new String()).toLocaleLowerCase(); // OK, treated as string
getObject(1).anything; // ERROR, typescript treat it as {} instead of any
```

but It doesn't work as expected when I don't pass `factory` parameter. How can I fix it?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xci2gs

Comment: How is that signature supposed to relate to the types you're describing? Why not use declaration merging?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it by changing the signature to

```js
function getObject<T extends Factory<any>>(id: number, factory?: T): T extends undefined ? any : ReturnType<T> {
```

Comment: You can also use overloads `function getObject(id: number): any
function getObject<T>(id: number, factory: Factory<T>): ReturnType<Factory<T>>
function getObject<T>(id: number, factory?: Factory<T>): any {
    let obj; // some entity from db in real app
    return factory ? factory(obj) : obj;
}`